# Convert a decimal number in Java into its assumed decimal Cobol representation

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting, cobol

I have a requirement to convert a regular number (most likely with 2 decimal digits) into its respective Cobol counterpart with so called assumed decimal point in the following format: `9(9)v99`.

I already have a way to right align and pad it with zeroes, which is part of the requirement, just need to come up with a generic way to convert something like `1234.56` into its Cobol equivalent: `123456`.

Is there any good way to do it in Java 8, or perhaps a framework that does Cobol formatting conversions like that?

Comment: If you speak of the internal storage format, then this depends on the `USAGE` of the Cobol decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented a little bit more with the existing Java facilities, and stumbled upon the `movePointRight(int n)` on `BigDecimal` type which seems to be doing what @rzwitserloot suggests but more declaratively.

Put together the below randomized test and ran it enough times (it seems)  to eliminate any edge cases, as the result comes out green:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    Faker faker = new Faker();
    String number = faker.expression("#{numerify '######.##'}");
    System.out.println("string: " + number);
    BigDecimal bdNumber = new BigDecimal(number);

    bdNumber.movePointRight(2);
    BigDecimal bdNumberMovedRight = bdNumber.movePointRight(2);
    System.out.println("bdNumberMovedRight: " + bdNumberMovedRight);
    
    BigDecimal bdNumberMovedLeft = bdNumberMovedRight.movePointLeft(2);
    System.out.println("bdNumberMovedLeft: " + bdNumberMovedLeft);
    
    Assertions.assertThat(bdNumberMovedLeft).isEqualTo(bdNumber);
}
```

here's a couple of random results that seem satisfying:

```
string: 062533.74
bdNumberMovedRight: 6253374
bdNumberMovedLeft: 62533.74
string: 882297.73
bdNumberMovedRight: 88229773
bdNumberMovedLeft: 882297.73
string: 638429.50
bdNumberMovedRight: 63842950
bdNumberMovedLeft: 638429.50
string: 500882.06
bdNumberMovedRight: 50088206
bdNumberMovedLeft: 500882.06
string: 922547.94
bdNumberMovedRight: 92254794
bdNumberMovedLeft: 922547.94
```

Answer (score 3):

Cobol just stores every digit as text. Non-60 year old languages store it in IEEE754. It's *far* faster and far more compact, but, introduces errors. Probably not an issue but you might want to read up on those. For example, in IEEE754 math, 10*0.1 != 1.0:

```
double v = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println(1.0 == v); // false
```

Because of that error.

First, you need to format your number to 2 decimals, which rounds away errors in just about every case:

```
public static String toCobol(double v) {
  return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", v).replace(".", "");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(toCobol(1234.56));
  System.out.println(toCobol(0));
  System.out.println(toCobol(1.234567));
  System.out.println(toCobol(-100.5));
}
```

prints:

```
123456
000
123
-10050
```

I assume that's what you are looking for?